# How to Timeout a request using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, timeout, html-agility-pack

I'm making a request to a remote web server that is currently offline (on purpose).

I'd like to figure out the best way to time out the request.  Basically if the request runs longer than "X" milliseconds, then exit the request and return a `null` response.

Currently the web request just sits there waiting for a response.....

How would I best approach this problem?

Here's a current code snippet

```
    public JsonpResult About(string HomePageUrl)
    {
        Models.Pocos.About about = null;
        if (HomePageUrl.RemoteFileExists())
        {
            // Using the Html Agility Pack, we want to extract only the
            // appropriate data from the remote page.
            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(HomePageUrl);
            HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='wrapper1-border']");

            if (node != null)
            { 
                about = new Models.Pocos.About { html = node.InnerHtml };
            }
                //todo: look into whether this else statement is necessary
            else 
            {
                about = null;
            }
        }

        return this.Jsonp(about);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make a small adjustment to my originally posted code

```
    public JsonpResult About(string HomePageUrl)
    {
        Models.Pocos.About about = null;
        // ************* CHANGE HERE - added "timeout in milliseconds" to RemoteFileExists extension method.
        if (HomePageUrl.RemoteFileExists(1000))
        {
            // Using the Html Agility Pack, we want to extract only the
            // appropriate data from the remote page.
            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(HomePageUrl);
            HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='wrapper1-border']");

            if (node != null)
            { 
                about = new Models.Pocos.About { html = node.InnerHtml };
            }
                //todo: look into whether this else statement is necessary
            else 
            {
                about = null;
            }
        }

        return this.Jsonp(about);
    }
```

Then I modified my `RemoteFileExists` extension method to have a timeout

```
    public static bool RemoteFileExists(this string url, int timeout)
    {
        try
        {
            //Creating the HttpWebRequest
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

            // ************ ADDED HERE
            // timeout the request after x milliseconds
            request.Timeout = timeout;
            // ************

            //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            //Getting the Web Response.
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
            return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Any exception will returns false.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In this approach, if my timeout fires before `RemoteFileExists` can determine the header response, then my `bool` will return false.

Answer (score 5):

Retrieve your url web page through this method:

```
private static string retrieveData(string url)
    {
        // used to build entire input
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // used on each read operation
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        // prepare the web page we will be asking for
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
        WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 10; //10 millisecond
        // execute the request

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
        request.GetResponse();

        // we will read data via the response stream
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;

        do
        {
            // fill the buffer with data
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            // make sure we read some data
            if (count != 0)
            {
                // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                // continue building the string
                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

And to use the HTML Agility pack and retrive the html tag like this:

```
public static string htmlRetrieveInfo()
    {
        string htmlSource = retrieveData("http://example.com/test.html");
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlSource);
        if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body") != null)
        {
          HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
        }
        return node.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your response, it got me going down the right path. Instead of reading the Html via `HttpWebRequest`, I simply added a timeout to `RemoteFileExists` - [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574109/how-to-time-out-a-request-using-html-agility-pack/6574626#6574626)

Comment: @reggie: Just a note that a production version of this code should use `using` for things that are `IDisposable` like streams.

Answer (score 5):

Html Agility Pack is open souce. Thats why you may modify source yurself.
For first add this code to class **HtmlWeb**:

```
private int _timeout = 20000;

public int Timeout 
    { 
        get { return _timeout; } 
        set
        {
            if (_timeout < 1) 
                throw new ArgumentException("Timeout must be greater then zero.");
            _timeout = value;
        }
    }
```

Then find this method

```
private HttpStatusCode Get(Uri uri, string method, string path, HtmlDocument doc, IWebProxy proxy, ICredentials creds)
```

and modify it:

```
req = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = method;
req.UserAgent = UserAgent;
req.Timeout = Timeout; //add this
```

Or something like that:

```
htmlWeb.PreRequest = request =>
            {
                request.Timeout = 15000;
                return true;
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard HttpWebRequest to fetch the remote resource and set the [Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout.aspx) property. Then feed the resulting HTML if it succeeds to HTML Agility Pack for parsing.

Comment: what would be the right way to convert a `System.Net.WebRequest` into a `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`?