# unable to read data from the transport connection the connection was closed

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library to read page's HTML, but facing this error:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection the connection was closed.

Here's my code:

```
var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();

for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
{
    var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(arr[j].ToString());  // error line
}
```

how can I extend the Timeout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574109/how-to-timeout-a-request-using-html-agility-pack

Comment: thanx
for the reply @bansi
i have got my solution here:
http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.in/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you get the html/texts first to your local machine before you load it to your agility pack. you can use **HttpWebRequest** it has timeout property if you really need to adjust it.

look on this >> 
[How can I download HTML source in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp)

Comment: actually i have done all my code using agility library.

Comment: good then, I just give you a other alternative for your timeout request.

Comment: i got the solution bro, thanx :)
http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.in/2010/04/using-htmlagilitypack-to-get-and-post.html