# C# HtmlAgilityPack timeout before download page

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want parse site https://russiarunning.com/events?d=run on C# with htmlagilitypack 
I'm try this make

```
string url = "https://russiarunning.com/events?d=run";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
```

But I got a problem - content on site loading with timeout ~1000ms
therefore, when using the web.Load (url) I download the page without content.

How make timeout before download page with htmlagilitypack ?

Comment: hi, How are you reading contents? are you reading specific html tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Timeout a request using Html Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574109/how-to-timeout-a-request-using-html-agility-pack)

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

Create one class as below :

```
public class WebClientHelper : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        return request;
    }
}
```

and use as below:

```
  var data = new Helpers.WebClientHelper().DownloadString(Url);
  var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
  htmlDocument.LoadHtml(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do this:

```
string url = "https://russiarunning.com/events?d=run";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
web.PreRequest = delegate(HttpWebRequest webReq)
{
 webReq.Timeout = 4000; // number of milliseconds
 return true;
};

var doc = web.Load(url);
```

More on Timeout property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2